# A different avatar on Math.SE., Physics.SE and Graphic.SE

Tags: discussion, support, bug, avatar

[image]

This morning I have seen that my avatar is changed in the other communities than TeX.SE. Why there is this change? How to have all avatars the same for each community?

Comment: Appears to be related to this on Meta.SE: [We're regenerating all Gravatar identicons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123). Some glitch occured, I think it will be site-wide at some point.

Comment: "**I really liked my identicon, can I get it back?**  
While we do not recommend you to continue using your old identicon, we can give you back the image so that you may upload it as a custom avatar. Please [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) asking for it and we'll be able to give you the image.". Save clicking on the link, but that's from the announcement so you can still get your TeX.SE one to use on the others if you ask them for the image of it